# In Android Studio 3.0 I am unable to find the layout width of type fill_parent.

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

In **Android Studio 3.0** I am unable to find the **layout_width** of type **fill_parent**. I need help that how to access this layout_width type. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `fill_parent` has been deprecated for several years. If you are using `ConstraintLayout`, use `match_constraint`. Otherwise, use `match_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"})
    @Deprecated
    public static final int FILL_PARENT = -1;

    /**
     * Special value for the height or width requested by a View.
     * MATCH_PARENT means that the view wants to be as big as its parent,
     * minus the parent's padding, if any. Introduced in API Level 8.
     */
    public static final int MATCH_PARENT = -1;
```

they have same values in "ViewGroup" class.